# Is the sum of the reciprocals of primes none of whose proper initial segments are primes converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

Is the sum of the reciprocals of primes none of whose proper initial segments are primes converge?

An example of those primes is $88547$, because $8,88,885$ and $8854$ are not primes.

The first few terms in the sequence ([A069090](https://oeis.org/A069090)) are:

```
   2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 41, 43, 47, 61, 67, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 127, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 181, 401, 409, 421, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 487, 491, 499, 601, 607, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 683, 691, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827
```

Comment: Why are you leaving out $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you, copy-pasting accident :) I edited

Comment: I would be surprised if we even know whether there are infinitely many such primes.

Comment: Not that it means anything, but just for fun the sum of reciprocals of first 1,411,151 terms (given in OEIS) is $2.009633895051...$, so far. Summing that many reciprocals of all primes yields $3.09020050299...$ for comparison.

Comment: @almagest , what are the list of multiples of 6 like this ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee ? You mean multiples of 6 with no initial segment a multiple of 6, or multiples of 6 with no initial segment a prime? But why are you asking me?

Comment: because if a prime of form 6k+1 ends in a 1, or 7, then the tens place up is a multiple of 6... @almagest

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee And so? We need **none** of the initial segments to be prime.

Comment: right I've shown a possible way to forgetting about last digits. turns out it's multiples of 3 ... not 6. see 37.

Comment: @almagest If there are only finitely many such primes then their reciprocal definitely converge so that would be easy :)

Comment: @almagest: "even" isn't quite right there. E.g. we don't know whether there are infinitely many twin primes, but we do know that [the sum of their reciprocals converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%27s_theorem).

Comment: Heuristically, the sum in the original question should diverge at the growth rate of $O(\log\log x)$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288648.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha: No, it converges (see my answer).

Comment: @almagest, Thanks for raising that question in your first comment, finally, there are infinitely many of those. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499099/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-none-of-whose-proper-initial-segments-are-prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series converges; the limit is approximately $2.48111396244$.

That the series converges follows from the [Kraft–McMillan inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality): A uniquely decodable code, and hence in particular a [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code), satisfies

$$
\sum_ir^{-l_i}\le1\;,
$$

where $r$ is the size of the alphabet and $l_i$ is the length of the $i$-th codeword. In the present case, the primes without proper prime prefix form a prefix code $\{q_i\}$ with $r=10$ and $l_i-1\lt\log_{10}q_i$, so

$$
\sum_i\frac1{q_i}=\sum_i10^{-\log_{10}q_i}\le\sum_i10^{-(l_i-1)}\le10\;.
$$

The series converges very slowly when summed directly. To compute the limit efficiently, consider the evolution of the set $S\subset[1,10)$ of reals that do not have one of the primes included in the sum so far as a prefix (in decimal notation, without the decimal point). For instance, after excluding $2, 3, 5, 7$ as prefixes, we are left with $S=[1,2)\cup[4,5)\cup[6,7)\cup[8,10)$, and upon excluding  the prefix $11$ this is reduced to $S=[1,1.1)\cup[1.2,2)\cup[4,5)\cup[6,7)\cup[8,10)$.

In each range of numbers $\left[10^n,10^{n+1}\right)$ approximately a fraction $\frac1{\log10^n}=\frac1{n\log10}$ of numbers are primes, so on the random model of the primes each such range reduces the measure of $S$ by approximately that fraction. For large $n\gt n_0$, we can approximate the measure $\mu_n$ left in $S$ by integrating the logarithms of the corresponding factors:

\begin{eqnarray}
\log\mu_n
&\approx&
\log\mu_{n_0}+\int_{n_0}^n\log\left(1-\frac1{k\log10}\right)\mathrm dk
\\
&\approx&
\log\mu_{n_0}-\int_{n_0}^n\frac1{k\log10}\mathrm dk
\\
&=&
\log\mu_{n_0}-\frac{\log\frac n{n_0}}{\log 10}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

so

$$
\mu_n\approx\mu_{n_0}\left(\frac n{n_0}\right)^{-\frac1{\log10}}\;.
$$

Thus, the measure of $S$ tends to zero. That means that except for a set of measure $0$, every $x\in [1,10)$ has a prime prefix in decimal notation.

This allows us to compute the desired limit far more efficiently than by directly summing the reciprocals. If a prime $p\in\left[10^n,10^{n+1}\right]$ were to contribute

$$
\int_{\frac p{10^n}}^{\frac{p+1}{10^n}}\frac{\mathrm dx}x=\log\left(1+\frac1p\right)
$$

to the sum, then, since all of $[1,10)$ is eventually covered, the limit of the sum would be

$$
\sideset{}{'}\sum_p\log\left(1+\frac1p\right)=\int_1^{10}\frac{\mathrm dx}x=\log10
$$

(where the prime indicates that the sum only runs over the primes without proper prime prefix). Instead, $p$ contributes $\frac1p$, which differs from $\log\left(1+\frac1p\right)$ only on the order of $p^{-2}$. Thus, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\sideset{}{'}\sum_p\frac1p
&=&
\sideset{}{'}\sum_p\frac1p+\log10-\sideset{}{'}\sum_p\log\left(1+\frac1p\right)
\\
&=&
\log10+\sideset{}{'}\sum_p\left(\frac1p-\log\left(1+\frac1p\right)\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

(Note that we're not relying on the specific form $\mu_n\sim n^{-1/\log10}$ estimated above, only on $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_n=0$.)

[Here's Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/606321277f5925d499f7e4624af31a4b) that finds the primes without proper prime prefix and sums $\frac1p$ and $\frac1p-\log\left(1+\frac1p\right)$. The sum of $\frac1p-\log\left(1+\frac1p\right)$ converges to double machine precision with $p\le10^8$; the result (plus $\log10$) is $2.48111396244$. By contrast, with $p\le10^8$ the direct summation of $\frac1p$ only reaches $2.01$. With $p\le10^{12}$, it’s still at $2.09$. Below is a plot of the partial sums of $\frac1p$ for $p\le x$. The abscissa is $\log\log x$; the ordinate is $-\log(S-S(x))$, where $S(x)$ is the partial sum and $S$ is the limit (as determined from the rapidly converging sum). Since the fraction of the sum that's missing at $p\le x=10^n$ is asymptotically proportional to $n^{-1/\log10}\propto(\log x)^{-1/\log10}$, we'd expect this plot to be asymptotic to a line with slope $-\frac1{\log10}$. The green line is a line with that slope fitted to the data. The good agreement of the fit with the data confirms the value of the limit.

[image: log log vs. log error plot of the sum of reciprocals]