# Are there infinitely many primes none of whose proper initial segments are primes. (OEIS: A069090)

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Are there infinitely many primes none of whose proper initial segments are primes? An example of those primes is $88547$, because $8,88,885$ and $8854$ are not primes. The first few terms in the sequence ([A069090](https://oeis.org/A069090)) are:

```
   2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 41, 43, 47, 61, 67, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 127, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 181, 401, 409, 421, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 487, 491, 499, 601, 607, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 683, 691, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827
```

Note: this question has been raised in the comments of a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3494219/is-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-primes-none-of-whose-proper-initial-segments-ar) about the convergence of the sum of the reciprocals of A069090, so [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3494219/is-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-primes-none-of-whose-proper-initial-segments-ar) could be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove this, we can use another closely related sequence: ***composites none of whose proper initial segments are primes***. In order to lighten the text, let's define the following references:

> **Type** $α$ integers: composites none of whose proper initial segments are primes.
>
> **Type** $β$ integers: primes none of whose proper initial segments are primes.

**Fact** $1$: It is trivially true that there are infinitely many **type** $α$ integers, because any sequence of even digits of any length that does not start with $2$ is a **type** $α$ integer.

**Fact** $2$: Any prime that is not a **type** $β$ integer, by definition, have $1$ or more prime initial segments, and the smallest of those segments is a **type** $β$ integer.

The last thing we need is a second conjecture, which has been proved:

> **Conjecture** $2$: For any positive integer $n$, there exist at least $1$ prime $p>n$ with the digits of $n$ as first digits.

See: [Proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers starting with a given digit string](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60825/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-starting-with-a-given-digit-s).

**Proof:**

Let $n$ be a **type** $α$ integer. Because of **fact** $2$, any prime $p$ with the digits of $n$ as first digits is either a **type** $β$ integer $>n$, or an integer with a **type** $β$ initial segment $>n$. Therefore, since **conjecture** $2$ is true, for any **type** $α$ integer, there exists a greater **type** $β$ integer. Because of **fact** $1$, we can conclude that there are infinitely many **type** $β$ integers.